# How to show QLabel on extended monitor

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

I have very simple qt application. My aim is that if I click on a button it should show message on my second/extended monitor. My application would be running on main monitor and display message should appear on second monitor. Thats how my method looks like:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   QLabel *ql = new QLabel();
   ql->setText("Order is Ready");
   ql->move(QGuiApplication::screens().last()->geometry());
   ql->show();
  .....
}
```

But this is not working for me.I have also tried but also not working :( Any help would be appreciated?

```
ql->windowHandle()->setScreen(QGuiApplication::screens().last());
```

Answer (score 1):

This sample doesn't "compile" for me, but try something like this - set coordinates

```
ql->move(QGuiApplication::screens().last()->geometry().width(), QGuiApplication::screens().last()->geometry().height() / 2);
```

Note: the question is which of your monitor is first and which is last...

Comment: Application is running on primary monitor and Message/Label should appear on secondary Monitor. I will test your suggestion

Comment: No.. its not working for me. I mean it shows label but the Label is on primary monitor

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Ensure that the window is on the virtual desktop the screen belongs to.
2. That it is somewhere on the given screen.

Thus:

```
void centerWidgetOnScreen(QWidget *widget, QScreen *screen) {
  auto *window = widget->windowHandle();
  Q_ASSERT(screen);
  Q_ASSERT(window);
  window->setScreen(screen);
  auto newCenter = screen->geometry().center();
  auto rect = window->geometry();
  rect.moveCenter(newCenter);
  window->setGeometry(rect);
}

void centerWidgetOnLastScreen(QWidget *widget) {
  centerWidgetOnScreen(widget, QGuiApplication::screens().last());
}
```